# android:stopWithTask="false" but the service did close

Tags: android

i have used the     android:stopWithTask="false"     but it never work with one of my services

```
<service android:name=".EcaService"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

and the service is:
    package com.example.ayham.usefullalarm;

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by ayham on 7/8/2017.
 */
public class EcaService extends Service {
    private BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        registerBatteryReceiver();
    }

    private void registerBatteryReceiver() {

        batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    if (MainView.eca_activeCode < 1) {
                        // How are we charging?
                        Log.e("in first if", ": done");
                        int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
                boolean wirelessCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS;
                boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

                if (acCharge || wirelessCharge) {
                    Log.e("in second if", ": done");

                    Intent do_Alarm = new Intent(context, BatteryAlarmView.class);
                    do_Alarm.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    MainView.eca_activeCode++;
                    context.startActivity(do_Alarm);

                }
            }
        }

    };
    IntentFilter electricalAIntent = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, electricalAIntent);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e("in the receiver","yay");
    /*Intent doAlarm = new Intent(this, BatteryAlarmView.class);
    doAlarm.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(doAlarm);*/

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

}

in the MainView the code is:

```
public class MainView extends Activity {
    static int eca_activeCode = 0;

    Button eca;
    Intent eca_intent;
    boolean eca_s;



    /*@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent itent = new Intent(this, MainView.class);
        startActivity(itent);
    }*/



    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_view);
        this.context = this;


        //to be used in decision of the eca
        eca_s = false;

        //initialize the eca button
        eca = (Button)findViewById(R.id.e_status);

        //initialize the textView related to the eca
        ecaText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EText);



        //add a click listener to the eca button to start the electrical alarm
        eca.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //decide whether to activate or not
                String s ;
                if(!eca_s)  {
                    eca_activeCode = 0;
                    eca_s = true;
                    s = "ON";

                    eca_intent = new Intent(context,EcaService.class);
                    context.startService(eca_intent);


                    }
                else {

                    eca_s =false;
                    s = "Off";
                    eca_intent = new Intent(context,EcaService.class);
                    context.stopService(eca_intent);

                    }
                //set the button text to indicate the status of eca
                eca.setText(s);
            }
        });



        //receive the battery alarm intent
        if(eca_intent != null) {
            Intent b_back = getIntent();
            eca_s = false;
            String s = "Off";
            String class_name = b_back.getExtras().getString("Class");
            if (class_name.equalsIgnoreCase("BatteryAlarmView")) {
                eca_intent = new Intent(context,EcaService.class);
                context.stopService(eca_intent);
                eca_activeCode = 0;
                //set the button text to indicate the status of eca
                eca.setText(s);

            }

        }
    }

}
```

what is wrong with the code, it did not give any error!!

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I have the same issue.